# Unit test not finding app setting

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Unit test is fail and I am getting below error message,

> Message: Test method ConsoleApp4.Tests.DemoClsTests.ExecuteTest threw
>   exception:  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: path

How to pass unit test?

Class Method

```
public class DemoCls
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        string dataFolder =   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"];
        foreach (string X in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dataFolder, "test" + "*.xml"))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Unit Test Method

```
[TestClass()]
public class DemoClsTests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void ExecuteTest()
    {
        var X = new DemoCls();
        X.Execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `dataFolder` is `null`, which mean that `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"]` is not finding a value.

Check the `app.config` file of the test project to see if app setting key `Path` exists with a value.

```xml
<apSettings>
  <add key="Path" value="<path here>" />
</appSettings>
```

How ever this code under test should be refactored to remove the tight coupling to too many implementation concerns. Mainly `ConfigurationManager` and `System.IO` via `Directories`

Comment: can we have mock for System.IO via Directories as test is looking for path which does not exist

Comment: You would need to refactor the class under test

Comment: could you help here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300478/system-io-directorynotfoundexception-could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-c-data

Comment: what refactor is required to pass the test

Comment: Checking that now

Comment: What do you mean. I do not understand your last comment